# Is there a way to format a number with commas for thousands, without converting the int to a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, formatting, int, number-formatting

I'd like to add commas to 'separate the thousands' when long integers are printed.
The catch is, I don't want to convert the int to a string.
There are a few questions in SO that suggest something like:

```
a = 1234567
print "The number is %s but it's converted to a string" %'{:,d}'.format(a)
```

====> The number is 1,342,424,242 but it's converted to a string

I was looking for a solution that wouldn't necessitate the conversion to a string.
For example, when I wanted to display a number as a percent:

```
b = 0.1234
print "The Norwegian Blue prefers kippin' on it's back! %0.2f%%" % (b*100)
```

====> The Norwegian Blue prefers kippin' on it's back! 12.34%

Anyway to do something similar, only with the commas separation?
Thanks!

**EDIT**: To better explain myself, I mean present the number with the commas, similarly to the way you present the percentage with a % mark and only 2 decimals after the point. You don't change the number, or transform it to a string, only manipulate the way it's displayed / presented. That's the sort of thing I'm trying to achieve.

**EDIT2**: I don't understand the negative sentiment here. I gave one way to go about something and asked if it could be done in a different way, that would be more similar to an example I gave. I arrived at both these examples after searching SO quite a bit. May be a noob question, but at least I had a go at it alone and looked for solutions before addressing the community. Not sure what I did wrong other than not knowing the answers. Tnx for reading.

Comment: Well that's not possible as comma separated integer would be treated as tuple object.

Comment: "Wash me, but don't make me wet" - you cannot have the one without the other. he formatting describes the way how the number is converted to a string.

Comment: You want to add commas...and keep the type as an `int`?

Comment: Formatting **is the process of producing a string**. You cannot format without that.

Comment: The first example does not convert `a` to a string. It just prints `a` with commas. `a` still contains an int.

Comment: You can not insert commas in a number, otherwise it would be a string. You can however, change the representation of a number, see below.

Comment: Your first example is **already** achieving what you want. It is **not changing the number**, just like formatting `b * 100` isn't changing `b` or `b * 100`, only formatting the number as a string.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but in the % example, what changes the way the number is presented is defined withing the '% reference' to the number outside the string. In the case of the commas, you do the manipulation outside, and the '% reference' is to a string. Can't I do something similar to %0.2f%% only to show commas for thousands?

Comment: @Optimesh: and what makes you think that `'{:,d}'.format(a)` didn't do the *exact same thing*? You can use `"The number is {:,d} but it's converted to a string".format(a)` by the way, there is no need to mix formatting styles.

Comment: I'm telling you, subclass the integer class in order to change it's representation with commas but retain its integer properties.

Comment: Is your problem that you converted the string twice? Just stop using the `%` formatting spec. This works: `print "The number is {:,} but it's converted to a string".format(a)`.

Comment: Would appreciate it if whoever downvoted read the second edit. Perhaps instead of "format" I should have used "present". Thanks.

Comment: @Optimesh: Could you give an example of what your optimal syntax for the first version would look like? I don't expect your optimal syntax to compile, but I don't understand what is broken with the first example that RedX's answer doesn't fix.

Comment: You seem to have a conceptual problem that is making this question hard to answer. `"%0.2f%%" % (b*100)` *is* string formatting. The number is being converted to a string for display. You can't display non-string things - the display device will still pick out characters to display, they will just be garbled.

Comment: @tdelaney Thank you. So in that case, I guess what I'm asking, or where I'm seeing a difference, is that in one case the styling is done inside the " " to be printed, and in the other - outside.

Comment: @Optimesh - yes, and I think solution as suggested below is to move to the new formatting style (`{...}`) completely. It has the richer display that you want.

Answer (score 9):

Your own example is able to do what you want. Just write it properly without mixing format styles:

```
a = 1234567
print "The number is {:,d} but it's converted to a string".format(a)
```

That's a good reason to use the modern syntax. It does not care about the type of the argument. It will use `str` on the object and output it accordingly.

```
print "The number is {:,d} and John has {} sisters and {} brothers".format(1000000, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, `a` itself is not being changed into a string. There is a temporary, anonymous string object created by `'{:,d}'.format(a)` and then fed to `"%s" %`:

```
>>> a = 1234567
>>> "The number is %s but it's converted to a string" %'{:,d}'.format(a)
"The number is 1,234,567 but it's converted to a string"
>>> type(a)
<type 'int'>   
>>> a
1234567
```

So `a` itself has not changed at all similarly as your second example does not change the object `b`:

```
>>> b = 0.1234
>>> "The Norwegian Blue prefers kippin' on it's back! %0.2f%%" % (b*100)
"The Norwegian Blue prefers kippin' on it's back! 12.34%"
>>> type(b)
<type 'float'>
>>> b
0.1234
```

So the underlying values of `a` and `b` are not changing. The issue is that you are using a less than clear syntax to print `a`. Just do:

```
>>> "The number is {:,d} but it's NOT converted to a string".format(a)
"The number is 1,234,567 but it's NOT converted to a string"
```

There is no need to do two formatting steps as you have in your example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess a major part of my question has to do from the confusion that the % formatting is seemingly determined inside the printed statement, whereas in the 2nd case it seems to be done outside of it.